# Why it is mandatory to mention logical source port creating flow classifier in neutron sfc

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

Why it is mandatory to include logical source port while creating logical source port while creating flow classifier in OpenStack neutron-SFC with ovs-driver.
I can create flow classifier by not mentioning logical source port without enabling ovs-driver.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not mandatory. The documentation just take some scenarios. You can leave it blank than that means you allow all port from protocol what you state (ex : tcp, udp or icmp)